# CRYSTAL REPORTS - Display all records where value appears multiple times in the table

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, combinations

For example, I have a report with twenty columns and I want to return **ONLY** the rows where the value in Column 9 appears more than once. I'm fairly new to this and so far I have not figured out an answer.

Other selection criteria includes date range, and service details.  The end result would be a report of members who received service more than once during the identified period.

I have seen a couple of examples returning only one column but I do not know how to apply that logic to my scenario.

```
SELECT "MASTERS"."MEMBNAME", "MASTERS"."MEMBID", "MASTERS"."OPT", "MASTERS"."HPCODE", "MASTERS"."CLAIMNO", "MASTERS"."CROSSREF_ID", "DETAILS"."FROMDATESVC", "DETAILS"."TODATESVC", "MASTERS"."ADMDATE", "MASTERS"."DSCHDATE", "MASTERS"."DATERECD", "DETAILS"."DIAGCODE", "DIAG_CODES"."DIAGDESC", "MASTERS"."PLACESVC", "DETAILS"."PROCCODE", "DETAILS"."HSERVICECD", "DETAILS"."PROCDESC", "DETAILS"."HSERVICEDESC", "P_MASTERS"."FULLNAME", "V_MASTERS"."VENDORNM", "MASTERS"."SPEC", "P_MASTERS"."CLASS", "DETAILS"."BILLED", "DETAILS"."CONTRVAL", "DETAILS"."ADJUST", "DETAILS"."NET", "DETAILS"."INTEREST", "DETAILS"."QTY", "DETAILS"."ADJCODE", "MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID", "MEMB_COMPANY_V"."BIRTH", "ADJUST_CODES_V"."DESCR", "MEMB_COMPANY_V"."SEX", "P_MASTERS_1"."REV_FULLNAME", "MEMB_COMPANY_V"."OPFROMDT", "MEMB_COMPANY_V"."OPTHRUDT", "V_MASTERS"."VENDORID", "P_MASTERS"."CONTRACT", "ME_V"."MEMOLINE1", "DETAILS"."COPAY", "DETAILS"."SEQUENCE", "DETAILS"."DATEPAID", "DETAILS"."CHECKNO", "P_MASTERS_1"."ACCOUNT", "MASTERS"."ADMTYPE", "MASTERS"."ADMSOURCE", "MASTERS"."CONTRVAL", "MASTERS"."STATUS", "MASTERS"."DATEPAID", "MASTERS"."CHPREFIX", "MASTERS"."NET"
 FROM   ((((((("Datawarehouse"."dbo"."MASTERS" "MASTERS" INNER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."DETAILS" "DETAILS" ON "MASTERS"."CLAIMNO"="DETAILS"."CLAIMNO") INNER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."V_MASTERS" "V_MASTERS" ON "MASTERS"."VENDOR"="V_MASTERS"."VENDORID") INNER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."P_MASTERS" "P_MASTERS" ON ("MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID"="P_MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID") AND ("MASTERS"."PROVID"="P_MASTERS"."PROVID")) INNER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."MEMB_COMPANY_V" "MEMB_COMPANY_V" ON ("MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID"="MEMB_COMPANY_V"."COMPANY_ID") AND ("MASTERS"."MEMBID"="MEMB_COMPANY_V"."MEMBID")) LEFT OUTER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."ME_V" "ME_V" ON ("MASTERS"."CLAIMNO"="ME_V"."CLAIMNO") AND ("MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID"="ME_V"."COMPANY_ID")) INNER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."DIAG_CODES" "DIAG_CODES" ON "DETAILS"."DIAGCODE"="DIAG_CODES"."DIAGCODE") LEFT OUTER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."ADJUST_CODES_V" "ADJUST_CODES_V" ON "DETAILS"."ADJCODE"="ADJUST_CODES_V"."CODE") LEFT OUTER JOIN "Datawarehouse"."dbo"."P_MASTERS" "P_MASTERS_1" ON ("MEMB_COMPANY_V"."COMPANY_ID"="P_MASTERS_1"."COMPANY_ID") AND ("MEMB_COMPANY_V"."PCP"="P_MASTERS_1"."PROVID")
 WHERE  ("MASTERS"."STATUS"='9' AND "MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID"='LWDLOM' AND ("DETAILS"."ADJCODE" IS  NULL  OR  NOT ("DETAILS"."ADJCODE" LIKE 'D%' OR "DETAILS"."ADJCODE" LIKE 'KILL%')) AND "DETAILS"."NET"=0 AND "P_MASTERS"."CLASS"='51' AND ("MASTERS"."HPCODE"='GSMH' OR "MASTERS"."HPCODE"='HENS' OR "MASTERS"."HPCODE"='SCAS') AND "MASTERS"."CONTRVAL"<>0 OR "MASTERS"."CHPREFIX"=2 AND "MASTERS"."STATUS"='9' AND "MASTERS"."COMPANY_ID"='LWDLOM' AND ("DETAILS"."ADJCODE" IS  NULL  OR  NOT ("DETAILS"."ADJCODE" LIKE 'D%' OR "DETAILS"."ADJCODE" LIKE 'KILL%')) AND "P_MASTERS"."CLASS"<>'51' AND ("MASTERS"."HPCODE"='GSMH' OR "MASTERS"."HPCODE"='HENS' OR "MASTERS"."HPCODE"='SCAS') AND "MASTERS"."NET"<>0) AND ("DETAILS"."FROMDATESVC">={ts '2014-01-01 00:00:00'} AND "DETAILS"."FROMDATESVC"<{ts '2015-12-31 00:00:01'}) AND "MASTERS"."DATEPAID"<{ts '2015-05-31 00:00:01'}
 ORDER BY "MASTERS"."CLAIMNO", "DETAILS"."SEQUENCE"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified query compared to yours. You should only need to add the COUNT() function to column 9 and the GROUP BY after the WHERE statement and before the ORDER BY statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(YourColumn9Name) AS YourColumn9Name
FROM Masters
GROUP BY YourColumn9Name HAVING (COUNT(YourColumn9Name)>1)
```